# Why can't I delete and rename these files in C

Tags: c, file

I'm working on a small side project about file-handling in C, and here I have a list of rooms (which has been sorted) and I need to have a `ViewList`, `borrowRoom`, and `returnRoom` feature.

All the features are working well, except on the `returnRoom` feature. My method of `retunrnRoom` in deleting the specific line with the room number that the user inputted is by:

1. Making the exact copy of the borrowed rooms list while skipping the specific line
2. Deleting the old file and renaming the new one (since this is a small file, this method is compatible).

I managed to create the new file with the copied content and skipped line. However, the `remove()` function is not working (it is returning `-1`), thus `rename()` function can't be done as well. Here is my code snippet:

(I would like to note that the use of struct elements is from the `struct` `room` that I used in the other part of the code to store the `status`, `borrower` (PIC), and `desc` (Purpose))

```
void returnRoom(){
char enter[5];
system("cls");
printf ("+======+==========+=================+===============================================+\n");
printf ("| Room | Status   | PIC             | Purpose                                       |\n");
printf ("+======+==========+=================+===============================================+\n");
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
    if (strcmp (room[j].status, "Borrowed") == 0){
        printf ("| %d  | %s | %s", room[j].roomnum, room[j].status, room[j].borrower);
        for (int k = 0; k < 16 - strlen(room[j].borrower); k++){
            room[j].spaceborrow[k] = ' ';
            printf ("%c", room[j].spaceborrow[k]);
        }
        printf ("| %s", room[j].desc);
        for (int k = 0; k < 46 - strlen(room[j].desc); k++){
            room[j].spacedesc[k] = ' ';
            printf ("%c", room[j].spacedesc[k]);
        }
        printf ("|\n");
    }
}
printf ("+======+==========+=================+===============================================+\n");
printf ("-> Return Room\n");
returnroom:
int roomReturn;
int flag = 0;
printf ("Please input the room number [0 to cancel]: ");
scanf ("%d", &roomReturn);
getchar();
if (roomReturn == 0) return;
temp = fopen("usagenew.txt", "w");
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
    if (j == i-1 && roomReturn != room[j].roomnum){
        printf ("Room does not exist\n");
        flag = 1;
    }
    if (roomReturn == room[j].roomnum){
        if (strcmp(room[j].status, "Borrowed") == 0){
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++){
                if (strcmp(room[k].status, "Borrowed") == 0){
                    if (roomReturn == room[k].roomnum) continue;
                    fprintf (temp, "%d#%s#%s\n", room[k].roomnum, room[k].borrower, room[k].desc);
                }
            }
            fclose (roomusage);
            fclose (temp);
            int deletefile = remove ("usage.txt");
            printf ("%d", deletefile);
            if (deletefile != 0) printf ("File failed to delete\n");
            else {
                int renamefile = rename ("usagenew.txt", "usage.txt");
                if (renamefile != 0) printf ("Renaming new file failed\n");
            }
            break;
        }
        if (strcmp(room[j].status, "Empty   ") == 0){
            printf ("Room is not borrowed by anyone\n");
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (flag == 1) goto returnroom;
scanf ("%[^\n]", enter);}
```

Weirdly enough, the code occasionally works correctly- it creates the new file as well as delete the old file. However, the new file won't pop out as it should be.

I guess there must be an error in my code, though I'm not sure where.
Would really appreciate an answer pointing to where I am wrong and how to fix it, rather than just giving a complete and ready piece of code for me to use. Thank you! :)

UPDATE:
I finally changed my method and decided to just overwrite everything in the same `usage.txt` file, thus (aside of some bugs that I am still trying to figure out) managed to get the `returnRoom` up and running. Thank you again :)

Comment: Protip: you're mixing UI code with file-management code. You need to _separate your concerns_ - and that will help with troubleshooting in general.

Comment: Ah! I'll change my code accordingly then. Thank you for the input :)

Comment: A couple of (unrelated) points about the code: Don't use labels and `goto` instead of loops, use actual loops. And even though different, a label like `returnroom` in a function named `returnRoom` is bound to cause confusion anyway. Also don't use `getchar()` to skip newlines. First of all there's a possibility that there's isn't an actual newline in the input at that point, and if you want line-based input then read actual lines (with e.g. `fgets`) to parse any way you need. There are also other (and better) ways to skip the newline (and any space) from being read by `scanf`.

Comment: Aside: `scanf ("%[^\n]", enter);` is worse than `gets()`.  Use a _width limit_ or better: `fgets()`.

Comment: Now for the problem: Keep track of all calls to `fopen` and `fclose` for the specified file. Make sure that each call to `fopen` is matched by a call to `fclose`. If you have more `fopen` calls than `fclose` then you have a problem. And don't keep the file open in other applications, that will also prevent the file from being deleted.

Comment: @bolakecil Do you really want spaces `"Empty   "` as used in `strcmp(room[j].status, "Empty   ")`?

Comment: Reduce your issue to a [mre] that only writes a new file, removes the old one, and renames the new. Check that this works, and only then proceed. Use `strerror()` to reveal the reason of failures.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the comments written, so I'm really sorry if I haven't replied to some :")
As to @chux-ReinstateMonica, yes I do, since I need them to position them correctly in the table. UI purposes, actually.

Comment: Ah, and I intentionally used `scanf ("%[^\n]", enter);` just to prompt the user to hit `enter` button before the code goes back to the main menu.

Comment: `scanf ("%*[^\n]")` would accomplish the same without a mysterious `enter` and risking buffer overrun.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for that! I'll try to track that down.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oooh,  I just knew now that you mentioned it, thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: @thebusybee I used `strerror()` and it stated `Unknown Error` though. Is there any more explanation to this type of error?

Comment: What argument do you give `strerror()`? Did you read its documentation? As a general hint: Always read the documentation of any library function you call. And make sure you understand what it says.

Comment: I did, and it stated that if the error code is unknown, it will print out `Unknown Error`. Oh well, I'm gonna dig more myself. Thanks for the input! :)